# Is war a verb in "If they come to war"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, nouns

I remember hearing a sentence in Game of Thrones season 3, it went like:

> Ser Barristan, *if they come to **war***, kill that one first.

Daenerys tells Ser Barristan to kill one of the rude master of second sons if they start a war. She said the above sentence.

I interpret this sentece in two ways:

1. If they come to **[the area of war]**, kill that one first.
2. If they come to **[war with us] ("war" as a verb)**, kill that one first.

I am confused which one is correct now. Can anyone please tell me if "war" is a verb or a noun in the above sentence?

Comment: The cited text isn't really either "idiomatic" or "grammatical" (and almost certainly never was; I don't think this is an example of a now-obsolete usage). I'm guessing it's something of a "mash-up" alluding to ***if it comes to war*** (if the situation deteriorates to that extent) and ***if they come in war*** (modelled on ***if they come in peace***, but the "war" version is very rare). AND ***if they come TO WAGE war***.

Comment: The meaning is the same whether it’s a noun or verb, so it doesn’t really matter. I’d lean toward verb, though.

Comment: In "come to [a state]", I'd be inclined to see the state as a noun; I've been dating her for a week; it's too soon to know if it will come to marriage, when my mother and her sister-in-law meet, they frequently come to blows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be parsed either way, but it looks verbal to me. "War" does have use as a verb, meaning "to start or engage in conflict"

It is somewhat elevated language as a verb, but she is speaking as a queen and dragon-woman.

Comment: It sounds more like a noun to me. _If they start a war/come to war_, meaning more like a war zone. But yes it sure has a verb form, I agree.

Comment: Compare with "come to play",  in which "play" is certainly a verb

Comment: For the purposes of a learners' site, I'm not sure there's much point in analysing the syntax / grammar. It's definitely not "syntactically natural", but very likely the scriptwriters "justified" it on the grounds that it's a bit "strange / exotic", which is exactly what they're looking for in a medieval fantasy context.

Answer (score 0):

War is not a verb in that context. It's an abstract noun.

"War" can be used as a verb meaning to engage in conflict, but not here. In this context, the verb use would be "If they war…". Is that clearly different?

Even in "… to make war”, "war" would be a noun. Prove that by comparison to "make words/shoes/ships/sealing-wax/cabbages/kings". The grammar is the same; the meaning should be more clear.

Consider being "at war" against being "at daggers drawn". Could "daggers drawn" be a verb? What about "each other's throats"?